# What is the diference between Margin and Padding and contribution of the bounding box?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is image to explain my question better

[image]

Every control has bounding box and every control has margins and padding. In the image The Gap between button border and the border of the bounding box is labeled as GAP-B, is this the padding or Margin?

Also there is gap between the two buttons GAP-A, is this the padding or margin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gap A is padding where as Gab B is Margin.

Margin is defined as the gap between the element and each border.

Padding is defined as the gap between the border of 2 elements

Comment: This accepted answer is wrong - the other answer is correct.

Answer (score 23):

Gap A is Margin and Gap B is Padding.

> Padding on second Border

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Border  Height="100" Width="400" >
        <Button  Content="StackOverFlow" Background="Yellow"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Padding="20" Background="Lime"  Height="100" Width="400">
        <Button  Content="StackOverFlow" Background="Yellow"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Padding]

> Margin on second border

```
    <StackPanel>
    <Border  Height="100" Width="400" >
        <Button  Content="StackOverFlow" Background="Yellow"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="20" Background="Lime"  Height="100" Width="400">
        <Button  Content="StackOverFlow" Background="Yellow"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Margin]

Comment: sorry im kind of got in to a complication with the first answer, Are you saying Margin is not the gap between the Bounding box of the button and the button itself?

Comment: yes. the gap for inside elements is Padding. and the gap for outside element is Margin

Comment: So you are thinking in terms of placing a control like button in cell of a grid. the gap between the cell border and button (bounding box of the button) is padding and the gap between the button and the bounding box of that button is margin?

Comment: Its getting confusing :) . The gap between cellborder and buttonBox can be Padding or Margin .You can achieve this gap by setting Margin in Button or by setting Padding in CellBorder.